# How do you provide frombody data to webapp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postman

I'm looking at somebody else webapp written in asp.net and it has a post request handler with this prototype

```
public class NotificationsController : ApiController
{
     public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string pns, [FromBody]string message, string to_tag)
     .....
     .....
```

I'm testing that post request handler with postman (Chrome extension) and providing pns and to_tag as url parameters. But how do I provide message parameter? I tried setting content-type as json and provide message in body as

```
{ "message" : "hello"} OR { "body" : "hello" }
```

But I'm getting 500 error code.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on what version of Postman you are using. But you will put your JSON in the **Body** tab and choose the 'raw' radio button also on the **Body** tab.

You will want to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. If you are still having issues, please add an image to your question of the Postman screen.

You will want to use: `{ "message" : "hello"}` for the body message.

Finally, the `pns` and `to_tag` parameters should probably also be given `[FromUri]` annotations so it is more clear that they are to be passed in as URL Parameters.

Comment: I found my mistake. I was enclosing values of url parameters with double quotes and that was causing the issue. Thanks for your help!